# Contact Form 7 submit button does nothing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I've set up a couple contact forms on WordPress using the Contact Form 7 plugin, but when I fill out the form and press send, the page seems to reload but otherwise does nothing. I've successfully set up forms with Contact Form 7 on other WordPress sites so I'm not sure what is going on this time. The validation on required fields still works, and the javascript on other pages still works, I'm not getting any error messages in the console, and I've commented out my own javascript code to ensure that there isn't a conflict. When I switch to the default contact form instead of creating my own, I still have the same issue. I've even switched to a default WordPress theme to see if it was my custom built theme that was the issue, but the form still didn't work.

The website I am currently working on can be found at centertitle.com. This is the only thing left to complete on my client's website before I let them know that it is done, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You do realize that in your HTML you have multiple forms with the same ID as well as nested forms right?

Comment: Seriously? Let me go clean that up and see if that does anything.

Comment: Good grief! That's all it was. Look at me being sloppy. Thank you!